# Extjs4 MVC, Ext.define() and Ext.create()

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

Firstly, My question is I want to know how different between Ext.Define() and Ext.Create(),
and I want to know how to use them in right way.

I reviewed my codes and many Extjs4 MVC tutorials,

and I found many many Ext.define() methods in Extjs4 MVC project.

I understand Ext.define() method create an object (CLASS).

And if I need a panel just for instance, I will not make any inheritance of the panel, also I will not reuse the panel after initialized.

Then, I think I need to use Ext.create() instead of Ext.define().

So, I try to change my code @.@;

In view, it was

```
Ext.Define("App.view.MyGrid",{
    extend : 'Ext.grid.panel',
    alias : 'widget.MyGrid',
    initComponent : function(){
        this.columns : [{ header: 'column' }];
        this.store : Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {})
    }
});
```

and I change to,

```
var myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    layout: 'fit',
    border: false,
    columns: [{ header: 'column' }],
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {})
});
```

After change the code, I got a problem that I can not retrieve(grep) the panel in Controller,

before I did this way before,

```
refs: [
        {
            ref: 'myGrid',
            selector: '',
            xtype: 'MyGrid', //view - alias
            autoCreate: true
        }
]

this.getMyGrid();
```

but after change, I don't know how to retrieve that panel in controller.

and while searching web to find out how to grep it, I just wonder '**Is it right how I understand about Ext.define() and Ext.create()? and why many people are using Ext.define() method even they not use again and not for inheritance?**'

please advice me to understand fundamentals of Extjs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My 2c: I **always** define stuff, and then just create it ( Unless its a 2 liner component ). This means that I can always reuse a component elsewhere, without even having to think about *whether* I would want to.

`Ext.define` also creates an error at page load, instead of component init/construct (depending on how code is written ), which, for me at least, makes debugging easier.

Also, it seems `Ext.define` is actually faster, which is kind of a big deal. http://jsperf.com/extjs-create-vs-define-create

`Ext.define` also tends to simplify the architecture ( in that it forces you to think about what a component is going to be called, and that lends itself to a file name, for the autoloader ( which incidentally is ANOTHER reason to use `Ext.define`  http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Loader)

`Ext.define`, with the `requires` keyword, also lets you play with creating custom builds of the sencha 
 package through the sdk ( http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools/ ) - I am somewhat unsure whether this is used in ExtJS 4 though, or only in touch.

Having sung its virtues, it is definitely trade-off between amount of files though, which is a complexity of its own.